# How can I export all my blog posts as CSV?

Tags: importing-exporting

I'm migrating my website from Drupal to WordPress, and the only content I have left to migrate over are all my blog posts.

From my research, the easiest way to do this would be to export my blog posts from drupal as a CSV and then import the CSV file to my Wordpress site.

However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to export ALL my blogposts. The only thing I've managed to find (from myPhP Admin) is 'content_type_blog.' However, that only gives me the 'front page tease' and not the whole blog post.

Where can I find ONLY my blog posts to export?

Answer (score 2):

If I was going to try to create a CSV of my sites content I would try to use the [Views Data Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) module and filter on your `blog` content type and include all the fields you want.

> This module is designed to provide a way to export large amounts of
>   data from views. It provides a display plugin that can rendered
>   progressively in a batch. Style plugins are included that support
>   exporting in the following types:
>
> - CSV
> - Microsoft XLS
> - Microsoft DOC
> - Basic TXT
> - XML

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with PHPmyAdmin:
Browse to the database, select SQL tab and enter:

```
Select t1.nid, t1.vid, t1.title, t2.body_value from `node` as t1 left join `field_revision_body` as t2 ON t1.vid = t2.revision_id where t1.type = 'blog'
```

That will get you the title and body - if you want dates those are also recorded in those tables so easy to get with minor editing of that SQL statement.

Then run it (click `GO`). Then to export as CSV scroll to the bottom of the page and click Export.

That'll take you to the Export page with that query as the source and you can then select any export format that PHPMyAdmin Supports.

Comment: How does your directions, as-is, create a CSV file?

Comment: @tenken ah hmm I suppose I should specify that to be of more use to other users - the OP was talking about exporting CSV from PHPMyAdmin so I was presuming they new that method.